# How to remove multiple steam users from a computer

Tags: steam, technical-issues

Several years ago a friendly, who is no longer my friend asked if he could sign into his steam account on my computer.

For whatever reason no matter what I do, I can't remove the his account data from my computer. It still pops up in big screen mode, and even "find your friends" in Epic Game's launcher.

His account was associated with fraud and I don't want that anywhere near my account. I also don't want valve to think I was the owner of that account. Is there anyway to permanently remove this data?

Answer (score 1):

Here's two places that the ex-friend's data or user ID might be.

- In your Steam folder there's a `userdata` folder with numbered subfolders for Steam users. In each one there will be a file `config\localconfig.vdf` and near there top will be a line 'PersonaName' identifying which Steam user this is, e.g. mine:

  ```
  "UserLocalConfigStore"
  {
      "friends"
      {
          "PersonaName"    "Rup"
  ```

  Once you've worked out which is your friends folder, try moving it out of userdata. (It's probably safest not to just delete it in case you get the wrong one: this will be most of the saved games etc. for this user.)
- In your Windows Registry (if you're comfortable looking there) there will be a key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam\Users`. Again there are sub keys here with Steam user IDs (but no way to identify the user that I can see, unlike the files above).

  In my case there's no data in each one, so it should be safe to delete without backing up once you've found the right user ID above. (But as always, be careful changing things in the registry.)